# django login through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am attempting to use django for my website. i implemented login using this code:7

```
user_django = authenticate(username=email, password=passw)
login(request, user_django)
```

which using django rest framework is working. But when i use it with an ajax request i think its not storing cookies.
i am also using a django function to check if the user is logged in:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Response('1')
    else:
        return Response('0')
```

but it always return 0. Do i have to do anything special on the client side to store the login information?

my javascript login:

```
function userLogin(){
    var user_email = $('#login_user_email').val();
    var user_pwd   = $('#login_user_pwd').val();

    var data = {email:user_email, password:user_pwd};

    $.ajax(prefix+ 'userLogin/', {
        success: function(output, status, xhr){
            $('#login_btn').click();
        },
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    });


}
```

Comment: Can you post the django log file?

Comment: this logs?[24/Mar/2013 11:26:45] "POST /api/userLogin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[24/Mar/2013 11:30:03] "GET /api/getOpeningAds/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 4121
[24/Mar/2013 11:31:29] "POST /api/userLogin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[24/Mar/2013 11:31:50] "GET /api/checkLogin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3
[24/Mar/2013 11:49:35] "GET /api/getOpeningAds/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 4121
[24/Mar/2013 11:49:51] "POST /api/userLogin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17

Comment: the problem is that django is returning "set-cookie" with the response but when i go to resources using chrome "inspect element" the session id isnt there?

Comment: function userLogin(){
  var user_email = $('#login_user_email').val();
  var user_pwd   = $('#login_user_pwd').val();

  var data = {email:user_email, password:user_pwd};

  $.ajax(prefix+ 'userLogin/', {
     success: function(output, status, xhr){
      $('#login_btn').click();
     },
         data: data,
         type: 'POST'
    });


 }

Answer (score 0):

This is a familiar problem to me and might be duplicate to other question on SO,

look at these, you will find the solution .

- [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)
- ["CSRF token missing or incorrect" while post parameter via AJAX in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django)
- [JQuery + AJAX + Django = CSRF ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214909/jquery-ajax-django-csrf)