# Forbidden error on jquery fileupload with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, file-upload

I'm using jquery fileupload with a django project. I want to add an additional field to my fileupload form . I followed [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) documentation. However, when I try to upload the images I get an `forbidden` error, django's console error is:

```
[14/Apr/2015 09:40:37]"POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274
```

My script is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
       var name = $('form#{{ opts.model_name }}_form').find('input[name="name"]').val();
       $('form#fileupload').find('input[name="image_name"]').val( name );
       data.formData = { 'image_name': name };
       if (!data.formData.image_name) {
          data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
          return false;
       }
     });
  });
```

My request is:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/upload/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 14 Apr 2015 08:40:37 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2,ko;q=0.2,gl;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:29144
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryURf6WD0fBem7roLF
Cookie:PHPSESSID=fqdqkmd9cmb3oi2odcd6ogiru7; _osra_session=TUNTZWJaWmJXRitBeFJuV1JRQm9BSEVvUklia3RtN1ZOK3NzUVNqcEpYcmlCeVhDWHE4K0JmdjF1RlkzODVmLzg2cTUreE1oQnp6Z0JKU3d4aGtHYmkyS0MzQVRQc1VYMDQ5WWFGYk56RGQxNDQxcmV5S1pJd0VvS0Mxc2MzS1laMkwwZlI0NFBDcDdsRDZPMW1mT0JyRUNaSXMyODdZcklCVFNsaER0RmdUM0xzbFRJMk9RSkZvSFRXUXNCc3hvNy9wMDhGb0o4M3hZdW1iWFFZTGdXU3RNTHFGQnNaVkpGTkwrY2IzdWRZQWJLeWt1VGR3cy94ZnRWRGVOTldlakF2Zm1xUFZGSnRxSXpkUU4rNWVWbHc9PS0tZTh2c3U5cjZmN1p6eDB6ZFNuTFN6QT09--2880fbb1b8182485ef09f12b95fd3e7c6d71a714; sessionid=asmv53nr7qc4f1ra930ux7zp29k0vdks; csrftoken=cqqQDJsMROiJa5AtzxVJshOYK49Hl2WL
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/admin/imageboard/image/add/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryURf6WD0fBem7roLF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_name"

asd
------WebKitFormBoundaryURf6WD0fBem7roLF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="4f9.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryURf6WD0fBem7roLF--
```

**asd** is the name I tried to send.

My example works if I don't add any additional data to my form.

What may be the problem?

**Edit -- Solved**

I followed these two posts to solve my problem:

1. [403 Forbidden error when making an ajax Post request in Django framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333098/403-forbidden-error-when-making-an-ajax-post-request-in-django-framework)
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

I used the [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) approach. I found it easier to implement ;).

Then in my javascript I added:

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
console.log(csrftoken);

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
  // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
   if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214909/jquery-ajax-django-csrf

Comment: What's the full error/traceback?

Comment: You cannot use post method without the csrf token unless you use @csrf_exempt

Comment: Thank you so much guys. You were right, was a problem with `csrf`.  I looked these two post to solve my problem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333098/403-forbidden-error-when-making-an-ajax-post-request-in-django-framework.