# Django Ajax form submission pointing to a 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery

I'm allowing users to remove posts through ajax. Posts have a boolean field live_until_removed. When set to false, the post disappears.

When clicking remove I'm given a 403, referencing:

`xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );`

How do I get this to run smoothly? Why this this error happening?

js:

```
$('#removeForm').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'), 
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('.close-post').html(response); // update the DIV
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

template:

```
<div class="close-post">
     {% if not post.live_until_removed %}
     <form class="" id="removeForm" method="POST" action="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Remove</button>
     </form>
     {% else %}
     <button class="btn">Removed</button>
     {% endif %}
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def post(request, id):
    ...
     if request.is_ajax():
          try: 
               post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
               post.live_until_removed = False
               post.save()
               response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Removed"})
          except:
               pass
```

Comment: Take a look here to how embed a csrf token in each AJAX request:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django/6533544#6533544

Answer (score 4):

You might have missed to send CSRF token in your request. Look at here; [Django-Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: I actually forgot to add the token {% csrf_token %}. It's doing what I need it to do on the backend, it just returns a blank page still referencing `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );`