# How to add image into a post in django

Tags: django, post, image-uploading, temporary-files

I'm building an blog system, which allow user add image to their blog.

when user add image, the image will be upload automatically, this happened before the blog is posted, so how should I handle the uploaded image, these image is kind  of like temporary image, because if the user post the blog, these images will have an foreign key to this blog , and saved into some folder,but if the user discard the blog , these  temporary images should be deleted.

the problem is how to get the firstly uploaded images,when the blog is actually posted? where should I store these temporary images? and how can I tell if the user discard the blog?

Comment: Is posting a blog post a single form with an image field? If so, nothing will be uploaded until the user is ready to POST the form so you don't need any temporary images.

Comment: no I build the blog on ajax, and use jquery-file-upload to upload image

Comment: its like facebook status

Comment: When user starts writing draft, BlogEntry object with draft status could be created on a server, when he attaches an images - they goes to that model related as `ForeignKeys`, when he posts the blogentry - entry just shows up in public, when discards - BlogEntry object being removed from the DB with related images. Lets say the model Image will correspond to and image in blog. You can override `delete` method of the model or attach a signal-receiver on `post-delete` signal, and attach add functionality that will delete files corresponding to Image object on image storage.

Comment: About discarding - you need just specify a conditions of 'discarding an entry'. I can imagine two variants - you can add special functionality for user for 'discarding' draft blog entries, so the server will receive a query for blo entry deletion. Or you can track user session - if during session, user do not post his entry in public, this entry considered as discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Modify the Post model to add a datetime field called *published* which allows NULL.
2. Use the field *published* to determine if the post is published yet or not. A post will be considered as a draft if the *published* field has NULL, published otherwise.
3. Create the post as soon as you hit the create post button. This will give you a Post object with the *id* which you can bind to a ModelForm and display to the user for editing. So when they add a picture, you can upload it and bind it to the *id* of the post in whatever way you want.
4. Change the *published* to the datetime.now() only when you hit the publish button.
5. Deleting a published or draft post should delete all of the linked resources like images.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the `django.contrib.auth` module to log users in and out? This has a middleware component that appends the current `User` object to the `request` parameter and works reasonably well with Ajax. It also provides redirects to log in pages if a user isn't currently logged in. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). A possible solution:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from filetransfers.api import prepare_upload, serve_file
from blog.models import BlogEntry
from blog.forms import BlogEntryForm

@login_required
def createBlogEntry(request):
    return render_to_response('blogEdit.html', { 'form' : BlogEntryForm() })

@login_required
def uploadImage(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = BlogEntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        newEntry = BlogEntry()
        newEntry = request.FILES['blogImage']
        newEntry.image = request.FILES['file'].name
        newEntry.user = request.user

        # delete unsaved previous blog post
        try:
            oldEntry = BlogEntry.objects.get(user=request.user,completed=False)
            oldEntry.delete()
        except:
            pass

        newEntry.save()
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'imageLocation' : '/static/media/blogImgs/%s' % request.FILES['image'].name }), mimetype='application/javascript')
  return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"error" : 101, "message" : "Big error!"}}), mimetype="application/json")

@login_required
def uploadText(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        newEntry = BlogEntry()
        try:
            newEntry = BlogEntry.objects.get(user=request.user,completed=False)
        except:
            pass

        newEntry.blogText = request.POST['blogText']
                    newEntry.completed = True
        newEntry.save()
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result' : 'success'});
  return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"error" : 102, "message" : "other Big error!"}}), mimetype="application/json")
```

The first method will display the page and form to create the blog entry and the others handle the 2 ajax calls for uploading the image and text. After the image has been uploaded the temporary `BlogEntry` is stored, if a previous entry has not been completed it is deleted now. When the text is uploaded the temporary blog entry is completed and saved.

It would be possible to have multiple temporary blog entries (for multiple tab in the browser - like this site), with perhaps a maximum number of items set. If the `django.auth.contrib` package is not being used it should be possible to use the session middleware instead - there are quite a few options here.

A sketch of the rest of the files:
**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class blogEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    blogText = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blogImgs/')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Delete image file also
        storage, path = self.image.storage, self.image.path
        super(ImageModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        storage.delete(path)
```

The delete method has been overridden to delete the image file after the entry file has been removed.

**template: blogEdit.html**

```
<html><head><title>New Blog Entry</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fileupload/8.9.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
form { float: left; }
#textForm {
width: 320px;
padding: 8px;
}
#textForm textarea {
width: 320px;
height: 150px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#imageForm {
width: 100px;
padding-top: 8px;
}
#blogImage {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
}
#imageForm input[type=file] {
margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="textForm">{% csrf_token %}
<textarea id="blogText" name="blogText"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="upload text" id="textUpload"/>
<img id="blogImage" src="/static/imgs/holdingImage.png" />
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="blogImage">
</form>
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/ajax/uploadImage/',
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        blogImage.attr('src', data.result.imageLocation)
    }
  });
});

$('#textUpload').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax/uploadText/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#blogText').val(),
      done: function(e, data) {
        if(data.result == 'success') {
            // display message / redraw edit area with complete blog, etc..
        } else if(data.error) {
            // error handing code
        }
      }
    });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This uses jquery-file-upload to upload the files.

There can be some issues with using Ajax and Django csrf protection see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). It may be required to copy the csrf token into the ajax call, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django/6533544#6533544). The Ajax done callback for the jquery-file-upload will load the uploaded image into the page, replacing the holding image.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class BlogEntryForm(forms.Form):
  blogImage = forms.FileField()
  blogText = forms.TextField()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import blog.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^createEntry/$', 'blog.views.createBlogEntry', name='createBlogEntry'),
  url(r'^ajax/uploadImage/', 'blog.views.uploadImage'),
  url(r'^ajax/uploadText/', 'blog.views.uploadText'),
  ...additional urls for django.contrib.auth
);
```