# How to return new csrf token at ajax POST in Django?

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-csrf

I have this simple Like button that works well when used with `@csrf_exempt`:

Template

```
<p id="like_count"> {{ topic.likes }}</p> 
<span data-type="topic" title="Like">       {% csrf_token %}
 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="liket" name="{{topic.id}}">
```

Ajax

```
$(function(){
$('#liket').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/like/",
               data: {
               'topic_id': $(this).attr('name'), 
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
               },
               success: tlikeSuccess,
               dataType: 'html'               
                });
    });

});
function tlikeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#like_count').html(data);
}
```

and views:

```
#@csrf_exempt 
def topic_like(request):

    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = request.POST.get('user')
        lu= request.user #User.objects.get(username= user)
        topic_id = int(request.POST.get('topic_id'))

        try:
            liked_topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)
        except:
            liked_topic = None  

        if TopicLike.objects.filter(liker=request.user.id, topic=topic_id).exists():

            liked_topic.likes -=1
            liked_topic.save()
            TopicLike.objects.filter(topic=topic_id, liker=request.user.id).delete()

        else:            
            liked_topic.likes +=1
            liked_topic.save()
            newliker = TopicLike(topic=topic_id, liker=request.user.id)
            newliker.save()          


    #args.update(csrf(request))
    args['likes'] = str(liked_topic.likes)
    return render(request, 'ajax_like.html', args)
```

However I don't like this workaround that ignores the CSRF, as it could be vulnerable. 
On the other hand, I could not manage to return a new CSRF token to the template so I appreciate your hints to integrate CSRF into this button.

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) suggest providing the csrf token in a header instead of in the post data.

Comment: @Alasdair please give me a complete answer. I don't know how to apply the doc's suggestions.

Comment: I think the docs are pretty clear. What did you try? What do you think is missing? Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 4):

Django in its [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) has defined to actually set the header on AJAX request, while protecting the CSRF token from being sent to other domains using `settings.crossDomain` in jQuery 1.5.1 and newer.

**Acquiring the token:**

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

**Setting the CSRFToken in the header:**

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Also try this method to embed CSRF token in each AJAX request given on this [SO link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533544/4921103)

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
    });
});
```

Comment: I added these functions to my ajax file and in my views removed `@csrf_exempt ` but I get this error in the consul `Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Do you mean I should add all the 3 functions above to my ajax.js without changing my original ajax function and views?

Comment: Just the first 2 methods, the last(3rd) function is an alternative to the 2nd function.

Comment: When I add 2 functions above to my ajax.js, I get `403 (FORBIDDEN)` regardless of  whether I update CSRF in the views or not. (Not I did not make any change to my original ajax function. Should I've had?)

Comment: These 2 functions are defined in the official docs on how to add a csrftoken to request. Please check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) if you have followed the exact procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the csrf token manually, using javascript.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to generate csrf manually it in my particular case?