# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect) Django error

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I am very new to Django. The name of my project is rango and I have created a URL named '/rango/tagger' that is supposed to send an object.

In my java-script, I have tried to communicate with this route by sending it an ajax request as follows:

```
function send()
{
  obj = {content:$("#content").val()};
  $.post('/rango/tagger',obj,function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

I have included the {% csrf_token %} in my template. However, it gives me the error as follows:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /rango/tagger
[31/Jan/2016 09:43:29] "POST /rango/tagger HTTP/1.1" 403 2274
```

My function tagger in views.py is as follows:

```
def tagger(request):
return render(request,'rango/index.html',RequestContext(request))
```

And I have also defined it in my URL pattern. I suspect my function tagger returns an incorrect value or data (made the change from HttpResponse(request) to the line above based on other SO solutions).

However, it does not seem to work for me. Where am I wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django

Comment: Also see the official Django documentation for using [CSRF with ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The AJAX request must include the csrf, because it's another HTTP request, so please copy this code:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

After you setup that before sending AJAX request to set the csrf.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)

Comment: Awesome! You rock!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it in a short way (without the codes written above), but sending all the data in the inputs field:

```
$.post(
    '/rango/tagger',
    $("#id_of_your_form").serialize(),
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django requires a csrf token for accepting post requests. You can also add a property
`csrfmiddlewaretoken = {% csrf_token %}` to your `data` if your `script` is inside the `template`.

For folks, using this inside an include js file, you can do something like:

```
<script>window.CSRF_TOKEN={{ csrf_token }}</script>`
```

and in your included `js` file use

```
$.post(url, { 'data': data + 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN },function(response){
    console.log(response)
  }
})
```