# Ajax Post Request Error using django 1.10.5

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

Over the last week or so I have been struggling to successfully implement a jQuery ajax request to pass data from a javascript function within my annualgoals.html to a django view in order to save data to my database. Currently I am just trying to test the data transfer by printing the data on the django end.

I have already checked out the following threads but cannot see any that show the same error as I can see (I am almost certainly missing something obvious).

[Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect) Django error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112451/forbidden-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-django-error)

["CSRF token missing or incorrect" while post parameter via AJAX in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django)

While a missing CSRF token was my first problem, the answers on StackOverflow and the django docs do a good job of explaining what must be done to ensure the csrf token is included. However, when following the recommended steps I receive the following django error:

response.set_cookie(settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

My code is as follows:

annualgoals.html

```
function getCookie(name) {
          var cookieValue = null;
          if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
              var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
              for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                  var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                  // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                  if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                      cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
          return cookieValue;
      }

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
          // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
          return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

// Ajax Setup

    $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
          }
    });

 // Ajax Call

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{% url 'LifeAdmin:saveAnnualGoals' %}",
      data: {'data[]': data},
    });
```

views.py

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@login_required
def saveAnnualGoals(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.POST.get('data')
   print(data)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^saveAnnualGoals$', views.saveAnnualGoals, name='saveAnnualGoals')
```

I am using Django 1.10.5 and Python 3.6.1

Any help would  be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks :)

Comment: Try  `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator for view, that renders page, from which user will make ajax-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view needs to return a Response. With your actual code, the view returns nothing, so `None`. Django then tries to add the cookie to the Response but as it is None, you get the error message you posted.

Example:

```
return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it was something so simple! :)