# Django jquery ajax cors error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-cors-headers

I get this error in the console when I try to post data with ajax. This data is supposed to be confirmed at this url and then I should get a response from it containing more data.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
reading the remote resource at https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans. 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  missing).
```

I am using django-cors-headers as middleware to add the headers. I followed all the config instructions.

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'corsheaders',
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'OPTIONS',
)
```

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

The data and url is declared above this and that part is fine. 
I only get the error alert everytime I submit it.

My packages:

```
Django==1.11.3
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
pytz==2017.2
```

I am on Windows 10.

EDIT: I added the csrfSafeMethod for ajax. I don't know if this might have something to do with it?. This code is provided by djangoproject here docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf

EDIT2: I ended up sending an ajax call internally so then I did the cross domain stuff with django using **urllib**. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) helped me a lot with posting data cross domain.

Comment: `CorsMiddleware` was added in the right order?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django) will probably help you.

Comment: @hanzTheFranz nah thats not the problem,

Comment: your url is `https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans`？

Comment: @Ykh yes that's the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
>   any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's
>   CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
>   before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
>   responses.

I would recommend you to put it as the first middleware (highest) among all the present middlewares.

Reference: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: Tried that, same error, however I used a different approach. See more info at the end of the question under EDIT2.