# Django - How to save javascript variable into Django Database?

Tags: python, django

I have a javascript variable called "counter", which I want to use to update a counter variable instantiated in models.py.

Here is a snapshot of models.py

```
class Player(BasePlayer):
    #track the number of times the user has lost window focus
    blur_quantity = models.IntegerField(initial=0)
```

Here is an example of pages.html

```
{% block content %}
<button name="blur_button" value=counter onclick="Warn()" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Blur Button</button>


{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script>
        var counter  = 0;
       // Tracks window blurs
       $( document ).ready(function() {
          function onchange (evt) {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
          }

          window.onblur = onchange;

        });  

        function Warn() {
            alert(counter);
        }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, whenever the user clicks the button, the value of "counter" should be stored somewhere.  How do I update the value of blur_quantity in models.py (e.g. my Django database) to reflect the value attached to the blur_button?

Comment: Along with Ajax, you should take a look at how to integrate CSRF with for security; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
   var counter = 0;

  $( document ).ready(function() {
     function onchange (evt) {
       counter++;
       $.ajax({
         url: '/update_counter/',
         data: {'counter': counter},
         type: 'POST'
       }).done(function(response){
         console.log(response);
       });
     }

     window.onblur = onchange;

   });
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import Player

def update_counter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        player = Player.objects.get()
        player.blur_quantity =  request.POST['counter']
        player.save()
        message = 'update successful'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from views import update_counter

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^update_counter/', update_counter)
]
```

Basically, the `ajax` in call in the JavaScript sends `counter` to the server via a `POST` request. `urls.py` routes the request to your `update_counter` method, which updates the database with the value of `counter`. Finally, the `update_counter` method returns a response, which is handled by the `done` function in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work on this.  Should I save urls.py in my root directory?  Is that the only line that it should contain? I am using the library otree, which only exposes me to views.py and models.py, so I've never seen urls.py

Comment: No problem :) `urls.py` will often go in the same directory as your `models.py` and `views.py`. I've updated answer to reflect what a urls file will often look like. I'm not sure how otree might affect this. I'd suggest having a look at the Django urls docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) for more info. Note that if you're using Django 2.0 it may look a little different than my example.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66610832/how-to-save-model-instance-in-django-through-javascript-in-html/66610915#66610915

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `onChange` method, you can send a `POST` request to one of your server's endpoint, and let the server updates the database from there. Then the server shall respond back as a response to that `POST` request with the most updated value of `blur_quantity`, and use this value as your new `counter`.

Comment: I know so little about this that it's hard to follow this answer, sorry.  I am currently running this all locally, and have two pages models.py and pages.py.  What would the post request look like?

Comment: This can be broken down to client side (js in general) and server side (django for your case).
Client: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send
You can look at this to learn how to send a POST request

Server side: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/
Look for the `request.method == 'POST'` statement and you can update your database from the `request.data`, and return a valid response

Comment: Thank you!  Will have a go at this