# How to save model instance in Django through JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, django-models

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem

**What i am trying to do**

I made a instance named `user_location` in model. I accessed it in `template` and I write `JavaScript` code to access `User's Location` using `JavaScript` BUT i want my model instance to save the  `JavaScript's Output country` in the Database.

**The Problem**

I don't know how to save model instance through JavaScript.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    user_location = models.CharField(mac_length=100,default'')
```

profile.html

```
<script>

$.ajax({
  url: "https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "callback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(location) {
    $('#country').html(location.country_name);
  }
});

</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>

#This is my model instance.

{{ profile.user_location }}
```

**What have i tried**

I also tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500189/django-how-to-save-javascript-variable-into-django-database). BUT it didn't work for me.

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax to send your data to the backend and let django do it's thing.

Comment: BUT how can i do it ? I never used ajax to save data in db before.

Comment: Use Ajax to send your data to django, receive it and then use django to save.

Comment: BUT i want it to save without save button. I mean it should be automatically save data.

Comment: What action should trigger the save function?

Answer (score -1):

You can use fetch api from javascript to storing the data from javascript in ur model db like fetch(your website route) where u had created your form for post request.
You can create post request on ur route to save ur db.
Example-url = "your website post request route"
params =
method:'post',
headers:
'Content-Type': 'application/json'

```
    body: data
fetch(url, params).then(response=> response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)
)*/
```

Comment: Can you please explain clean ?

Comment: Oh i had pasted full code of javascript but i dont know why the code is broken i can give advice to read the fetch api of javascript or if u using jQuery ajex you can use post request which will post your data to ur db

Comment: OKay Thanks, I will try in few minutes