# Matching query does not exist ERROR: "__.models.__.DoesNotExist: __ matching query does not exist."

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to send data to my database using Django Models and Views file but I'm continuously getting this error:
"raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
crm.models.Time_Stamps.DoesNotExist: Time_Stamps matching query does not exist."

I do have 'Time_Stamps' as a Model in models.py file.

How to resolve it?

**views.py**

```
def update_counter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        timestamp = Time_Stamps.objects.get()
        counterValue = request.POST['counter']
        #timestamp.Task_ID = counterValue
        timestamp.startTime = request.POST['timestamp']
        print(counterValue)
        print(startTime)
        timestamp.save()
        message = 'update successful'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**models.py**

```
class Time_Stamps(models.Model):
    TimeStamp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.TimeStamp
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'TimeStamps'
```

**ERROR**

```
......................
File "C:\Users\kushw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
crm.models.Time_Stamps.DoesNotExist: Time_Stamps matching query does not exist.
[24/Sep/2021 15:44:27] "POST /update_counter/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73227
```

Comment: `Time_Stamps.objects.get()` is throwing exception due to no record in database. I can guide you if you can let me know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to store a JavaScript variable in the database using Ajax which is in one of my HTML files.

Comment: That variable is `timestamp`?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `Time_Stamps.objects.get()`?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be an actual "Timestamp" variable but as of now it's just an integer.

Actually I'm trying to something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500189/django-how-to-save-javascript-variable-into-django-database

Comment: I'm using "Time_Stamps.objects.get()" to give it a reference (I guess). Actually I'm new in Django and I just tried copying the solution from that previous link.

Comment: You need to read Django documentation regarding how to make queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/. `Time_Stamps.objects.get()` will work only if there is only one record in database, otherwise it will throw exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. :)
Instead of using "timestamp = Time_Stamps.objects.get()", I need to use "timestamp = Time_Stamps(TimeStamp='SomeValue').