# Django Python: Can't access JS object passed via AJAX from Python QueryDict

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

In this Django project I'm building, I have data going back and forth between server and client via javascript and python using AJAX. For convenience I devised a `config` object in JS to carry over important parameters the server and responding JS need to know. On the Python side I am unable to access this object because it is `None`, but printing the object out to the JS console before sending and printing the POST object out to the Py console both show something is there. I don't understand why accessing the JS object (not it's memebers) in the `QueryDict` comes back as None.

```
# JavaScript   

var objConfig = {
   param1: "more text data",
   param2: "more text data",
   param3: "more text data",
};

console.log(objConfig);

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: strCsrfToken,
      strTextData: strTextData,
      objConfig: objConfig
   },
   success: callback
});

# JS console output:
# Object {param0: "more text data", param1: "more text data", param2: "more text data"}


# Python
def DoTheThing(response):
   print(response.POST.get('strTextData'))
   print(response.POST.get('objConfig'))
   print(response.POST)
   print(response.POST.get('objConfig[param0]'))

# Python console output:
# Text data being sent to server.
# None
# <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'strTextData': ['Text data being sent to server.'], 'objConfig[param0]': ['more text data'], 'objConfig[param1]': ['more text data'], 'objConfig[param2]': ['more text data']}>
# more text data
```

Notice how `print(response.POST.get('objConfig'))` prints `None`, but `print(response.POST.get('objConfig[param0]'))` prints exactly what I'd expect.
I have also noticed in the `QueryDict` that it doesn't seem to have `objObject` represented as an object like how I was expecting. I understand to due differences between JS and Py objects, but it has each member of the object listed individually using an array index operator which I'm not sure why or how to use properly.

I can't just get the whole `objConfig` object, I need to access each member individually? Also how would this work trying to send `objConfig` in an HttpResponse? I devised the this kind of object pattern to save time and text space writing out each parameter individually for how I want this data to be handled going between server and client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `Content-Type` of `$.ajax()` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` the issue should be solved if you change it to `application/json`.

Example:

```
var data = {
    strTextData: strTextData,
    objConfig: objConfig
}

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   headers: { "X-CSRFToken": strCsrfToken },
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   success: callback
});
```

Check more info on the [Jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

On you view you should:

```
import json
...
# on the view
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: I gave this a try and something goes awry with the CSRF token when I change the content type. It says "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect) just by adding that one line. Currently investigating.

Comment: Okay, so changing the content type is changing the CSRF Token I need to pass in for security reasons.

Comment: Just edited / fixed, but you can get more details on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django

Comment: That works! But now there's no POST data when I print `request.POST` to the console. I found my data in `request.body` which is in a very strange format.
<br><br>
`b'strTextData=Text%20data%20to%20be%20sent%20to%20server.&objConfig%5Bparam0%5D=more%20text%20data&objConfig%5Bparam1%5D=more%20text%20data&objConfig%5Bparam2%5D=more%20text%20data`

Comment: Added more info to the answer. To be have to handle the object with multiple layers of nested attributes you should parse the json content on the request body.